# MailApp.sendEmailで送信について;

Tags: google-spreadsheet, gmail

はじめまして。現在、Bloggerで申込み受付のフォームを作成しています。申込み者に対して申込み内容の確認用に自動返信のメールをスプレッドシートからスクリプトで送信しています。現在ブログ自体は限定公開しています。
MailApp.sendEmailで送信しているはずのものが受信できていない現象がでていて、困惑しています。それは、２つのパターンがあります。
１
ブログを閲覧し、申込みをしているデバイス（iphone）と違うデバイス（パソコン（windows）＜iphoneにはそのメールアドレスが登録されていない＞）のメールアドレスに送信すると、Gmailの送信済みフォルダには確かに送信した記録が残っているのですが、違うデバイス（パソコン（windows）のメーラーには届いていません。
２
ブログを閲覧し、申込みをしているデバイス（ipad）と違うデバイス（スマホ（andoroid）＜ipadにはそのメールアドレス（imail)が登録されていない＞）のメールアドレスに送信すると、Gmailの送信済みフォルダには送信済みフォルダに記録が残っていない。そもそも送信されていない。

困惑しています。解決方法を教えてくださると大変助かります。いずれのメールアドレスも限定公開の読者対象のアドレスです。

Answer (score 2):

「送信済みメール」にメールがある場合は、宛先のメールアドレスが間違っているか、宛先のサーバで迷惑メール扱いされていることが考えられます。

「送信済みメール」にメールがない場合は、GmailApp.sendEmailが実行されるまでにスクリプトでエラーが発生して中断してしまっているのではないでしょうか。スクリプトエディタの「表示」-「実行トランスクリプト」の内容や、スクリプトに`Logger.log()`を追加して「表示」-「ログ」を確認するなどして原因を調べそれを取り除いてください。

Comment: 質問を朝、削除してしまいました。すみません。
回答ありがとうございました。 1つ目のパターンだと、最後の処理で申込者に返信したものと同じ自動返信メールを自分のアドレスにも送信している点とGmailの送信済みフォルダに送信の記録があった点で、スクリプトがエラーを起こしているとの認識はありませんでした。確かにサーバーで迷惑メール扱いされているのかもしれません。
2つ目のパターンだと、自分のアドレスにも送信されず、どこかでエラーになっているとの認識はありました。最後の処理にまでいっていないので、確かに中断していると思います。 ただ、1つ目も2つ目も何か別の処理が走っているわけではないのでどうして違いがでてくるのかわかりませんでした。
今日あらためて、テストをしてもらったら、2つ目のパターンでも自動返信メールを自分のアドレスにも送信し、Gmailの送信済みフォルダに送信の記録が残りました。 さらに、携帯用のメールサーバーが受信拒否しているとのエラーメールが戻ってきました。これは、投稿前には来なかったので、不思議です。 おっしゃる通り、デバッグログの確認をもう一度してみます。
ありがとうございました。